# Запрос SQL из двух таблиц

Tags: php, sql

Я - новенькая, никак не могу справиться с проблемой: Есть две таблицы первая с поварами и вторая с их рецептами. Получается вывести все рецепты всех поваров но я не могу понять как вывести все рецепты только одного повара. Помогите пожалуйста.

Table cook :

```
`cookID` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `firstname` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `lastname` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `photo` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
```

Table recipe :

```
`recipeID` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `intro` text NOT NULL,
  `diff` text NOT NULL,
  `time` text NOT NULL,
  `cost` text NOT NULL,
  `cookID` int NOT NULL,
```

```
    public function readAll() {
        $cnx = $this->connexion();
        $rs = $cnx->prepare('SELECT * FROM recipe LEFT JOIN cook ON recipe.cookID = cook.cookID');
        $rs->execute();
        $recipes = false;
        while ($data = $rs->fetch(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
        {
            $recipe = new Recipe();
            $recipe->setRecipeID($data['recipeID']);
            $recipe->setTitle($data['title']);
            $recipe->setIntro($data['intro']);
            $recipe->setDiff($data['diff']);
            $recipe->setTime($data['time']);
            $recipe->setCost($data['cost']);
            $recipe->setCookID($data['cookID']);
            
        }
        return $recipes;
    }
```

Comment: И что же именно не работает? Кроме того, что у вас в описании таблиц и в коде имена полей не совпадают.

Comment: LEFT JOIN возвращает все записи левой таблицы (в запросе это таблица `recipe`) вне зависимости от условий связывания.

Comment: Ну как бы в этом и смысл. Не вижу в запросе никаких услови, кстати

Comment: Вообще, если нужны рецепты одного конкретного повара, то `left join` не нужен и должно быть условие вида `where cookID = 1`

Comment: в том то и дело что не для одного конкретного, а для разных, не пойму какое нужно условие для такого случая, повара же с каждым запросом меняться будут. наверное нужно выводить из таблицы cook? Попробовала так : ( 'SELECT * FROM cook LEFT JOIN recipe ON cook.cookID = recipe.cookID WHERE cook.cookID =:cookID '); но выдается только первый рецепт повара, а остальные его рецепты нет ...

Comment: Выложите полные, а не кастрированные, CREATE TABLE таблиц. Дайте пример содержимого таблиц (2-3 повара, по 2-3 рецепта на рыло) в виде INSERT INTO скриптов. Покажите требуемый результат запроса для именно таких исходных данных. "вывести все рецепты только одного повара" - в смысле одного определённого повара, или рецепты, которые присутствуют только у одного (хоть какого-нибудь) повара?

Comment: Таки всё ещё непонятно чем такой запрос плох? select * from recipe where cookID = 42;

Comment: $recipes = false; return $recipes; у тебя всегда  ложь возвращается?

Comment: Этот запрос прекрасно работает :  ( 'SELECT * FROM cook LEFT JOIN recipe ON cook.cookID = recipe.cookID WHERE cook.cookID =:cookID '); и с указанием where cookID = 1 тоже, но дело в том, что cookID должны меняться в зависимости от выбора пользователя. Мне нужно получить из запроса все рецепты выбранного повара.
Как это сделать? Надо где-то указать $recipe->setCookID($_POST['cookID']); ?